# Unhandled runtime error (error connection timeout)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios

I am trying to upload an image to my admin panel being built with next.js and i am getting an axios error: request failed with status code 500. below is the function call

```
  async function uploadImages(ev) {
  const files = ev.target?.files;
    if (files?.length > 0) {
        const data = new FormData();
        for (const file of files) {
            data.append('file', file);
        }
        const res = await axios.post('/api/upload', data);
        setImages(oldImages => {
            return [...oldImages, ...res.data.links];
        });
    }
}


also find below the api call 

  import multiparty from "multiparty";
  import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
  import * as fs from 'fs';
  import mime from 'mime-types'

  const bucketName = "nomso-next-ecommerce";


  export default async function handle(req, res) {


const form = new multiparty.Form();
const {fields,files} = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve({fields, files});
    });
});
console.log("length:", files.file.length);
const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
});
const links = [];
for (const file of files.file) {
    const ext = file.originalFilename.split('.').pop();
    const newFilename = Date.now() + '.'+ ext;
    await client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: newFilename,
        Body: fs.readFileSync(file.path),
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: mime.lookup(file.path),
    }));
    const link = `https://${bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/${newFilename}`;
    links.push(link);
}
return res.json({links});

}
export const config = {
api: {bodyParser: false},
};
```

I want to upload the image and save it to my mongodb database as a collection for a product in my admin dashboard of my ecommerce application.